# Using Google Fusion Tables to read Wordpress database... which in turn creates map. Can it be done?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Is it possible for Google Fusion Tables to read my Wordpress database? If so, how?

I have custom wordpress fields which contain addresses for several hundred companies. Ideally I want Google Fusion Tables to read the database.

Hopefully this will overcome two major problems 1. Avoid the geocode limit (currently done using a time delay, which isn't ideal). 2. Obfuscate my data so it's protected.

Really need someone's help with this.

Comment: Google Fusion Tables are a database - so you want to COPY from your wordpress database to your fusion table?

Comment: @Mapperz Yes, I want to copy specific data from my wordpress db to the fusion db. If it can be done automatically then even better.

Comment: Interesting. Now, I have no idea if this will work, as I have never worked with Fusion Tables, but I think it's worth looking into. What about using PHP to push your database content out to XML, as in [this Google Maps API article](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html)? Basically it queries the table and pushes the result out to a XML file, then Google Maps reads it. Can this also be done for Fusion Tables - have it read the dynamic XML file?

Comment: @ChadCooper I'm completely open to whatever method gets the job done, I've googled it to death and there's not much to go on. So your saying to save the wordpress data as an xml file (not sure how to do that!) and get the fusion table to read the xml file, therefore keeping everything automatic, right?

Comment: Not sure this is GIS SE question but Yes Export your Wordpress DB http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/ csv format - load in csv into fusion tables comma-separated text (.csv) 100mb limit -

Comment: Sorta. The link to the Google Maps API example explains it better, but it uses PHP to query your database (in your case your WP table), push the query results to a XML file, then maybe somehow have your Fusion Table slurp in that XML with every map request...maybe?

Comment: @ChadCooper I think the first part is achievable, it's getting the fusion table to read the dynamic xml file and continually update it's table content, I don't think that can be done can it?

Comment: @Rob - not sure if Fusion Tables can read the XML, it was just an idea to look into.

Comment: @ChadCooper I think I could use a csv but again I don't think fusion tables has any kind of auto import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to export your table to csv
2. Maybe use google refine to improve the data of your articles csv
3. Import csv in a Fusion Table
4. Geocode the table, its a feature in the user interface, you Geocode by the column "Article text" where the addresses are
5. Click on the map view, and you could view the points, some of them will be missing because of an unsuccessful geocoding

If only want to know if it is possible the answer is yes, the limit is the geocoding capacity of google to get addresses inside your text.

1. You can geocode by yourself using geonames or another Geocoding API

Answer (score 0):

There's no point and click way to do this.  But hiring someone to write the script you need is not hard.  The script must read your WordPress database, then write to fusion tables using the Fusion Tables SQL API.  Maybe a $100-$200 job.  Then you need a way to run the script every so often (nightly?).  Your web host may have "cron" jobs available for this purpose.